# AvalonDock programmatically add control to LayoutAnchorable

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I have the following code to add an LayoutAnchorable  to an LayoutAnchorablePane but I don't know how to add a control such as a textbox to a LayoutAnchorable

```
InitializeComponent();

LayoutAnchorablePane anchorablePane = new LayoutAnchorablePane();

LayoutAnchorable layoutAnchorable = new LayoutAnchorable();

layoutAnchorable.Title = "Dock1";

anchorablePane.Children.Add(layoutAnchorable);

anchorablePaneGroup.Children.Add(anchorablePane);
```

There are no Children property for LayoutAnchorable that I can see so I can not use the same method.

Edit: From looking at the documentation, this can be done by simply

```
layoutAnchorable.Content = new TextBox();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the content of a `LayoutAnchorable` you do use the `Content` property :

Take a look at the documentation : [link](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout.LayoutContent~Content.html)